# Strong resin for fibreglass

Tags: pressure, strength

Is there a binding material that could be reinforced with woven glass fibres cloth for tensile strength, but which offers reasonable containment against high pressure when used minimally? Ie optimising for thinness.

As I see it, the challenge is how be effective in preventing the fibres of the cloth from separating enough to create a weak point which would then burst, meaning the substance needs to have reasonably high tensile strength itself.

Comment: You're looking for a material with high fracture toughness/energy.  Elastomeric resins come to mind, but they don't bond well to glass without chemical treatment. Go to a manufacturer's site (e.g.,https://www.elastochem.co.nz/)  to check material data to see what options you have.

Comment: Lacks detail: what material(s) are you bonding / joining? will the resin cure / link to that material? Is this a joint or a repair? crack or hole?

Comment: @Solar bonding to nothing else but glass fibre. I want to create a standalone panel. I suppose assume that the glass is treated/primed so it bonds with the resin/glue/whatever material.

Comment: @Bohemian, I think the glass fibre is treated so that it softens when wetted with the resin. Have a look at [Soup Classic Motoring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjnJAR-MBiQ&ab_channel=SoupClassicMotoring) at about 18 minutes in. This guy does stop-motion car restoration videos which are rather fantastic for the amount of time it must take him.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem with the standard isothalic polyesther resin ? It is used for high strength sucker rods and most other things. Nearly all the strength is in the glass. For pressure tightness add a surface gel coat.